# merge multiple arrays and use foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have 3 arrays and want to merge them together.
So i can use it in ONE foreach

```
<?php 
print_r($zaza_optionsbase['header-icon-title']);
print_r($zaza_optionsbase['header-icon']);
print_r($zaza_optionsbase['header-icon-link']);
?> 


ARRAY ( [0] => FIRST TITLE [1] => SECOND TITLE [2] => THIRTH TITLE )
ARRAY ( [0] => FA FA-HEART [1] => FA FA-POWER-OFF [2] => FA FA-TH )
ARRAY ( [0] => LINK1 [1] => LINK2 [2] => LINK3 )
```

Something like below.. but i can't get it to work

```
<?php 
$newArray = array($zaza_optionsbase['header-icon-title'], $zaza_optionsbase['header-icon'], $zaza_optionsbase['header-icon-link']);

foreach ($newArray as $item)
{
    echo '<a href="'.$item['header-icon-title'].'"><i class="'.$item['header-icon-icon'].'"></i>'.$item['header-icon-link'].'</a>';
}
?>
```

Thanx in advanced

it must output:

```
    echo '<a href="'.$item['header-icon-title[1]'].'"><i class="'.$item['header-icon-icon[1]'].'"></i>'.$item['header-icon-link[1]'].'</a>';
    echo '<a href="'.$item['header-icon-title[2]'].'"><i class="'.$item['header-icon-icon[2]'].'"></i>'.$item['header-icon-link[2]'].'</a>';
    echo '<a href="'.$item['header-icon-title[3]'].'"><i class="'.$item['header-icon-icon[3]'].'"></i>'.$item['header-icon-link[3]'].'</a>';
```

Comment: you can `+` arrays, so `foreach($arr1 + $arr2 + $arr3 as $foo)` may work for you.

Comment: What exactly would the expected output be?

Comment: So you want to loop through 3 arrays simultaneously?

Comment: It should output:<br><br>        echo '<a href="'.$item['header-icon-title[1]'].'"><i class="'.$item['header-icon-icon[1]'].'"></i>'.$item['header-icon-link[1]'].'</a>';<br>
  echo '<a href="'.$item['header-icon-title[2]'].'"><i class="'.$item['header-icon-icon[2]'].'"></i>'.$item['header-icon-link[2]'].'</a>';<br>
  echo '<a href="'.$item['header-icon-title[3]'].'"><i class="'.$item['header-icon-icon[3]'].'"></i>'.$item['header-icon-link[3]'].'</a>';

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all of your arrays into `array_map` instead of using `foreach`.

```
array_map(function($title, $icon, $link) {
    echo '<a href="'.$title.'"><i class="'.$icon.'"></i>'.$link.'</a>';
}
, $zaza_optionsbase['header-icon-title']
, $zaza_optionsbase['header-icon']
, $zaza_optionsbase['header-icon-link']);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!... Thanx